# Service workers caching ressources from disk cache

Tags: service-worker

I am creating a web app that need offline support and updates. When I update app, the new service worker start caching files from the disk cache and don't update the app. This cause the new cache to get old files.
[Screenshot of chrome network debbuging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAegN.png).

```js
const STATICCACHE = 'v9';
const DYNCACHE = 'dv2';
//v9
const assets = [
// All my assets
];

// install
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(STATICCACHE).then(cache => {
            console.log("caching assets");
            cache.addAll(assets);
        })
    );

});

// activate event
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(keys => {
            return Promise.all(keys
                .filter(key => key !== STATICCACHE && key !== DYNCACHE)
                .map(key => caches.delete(key))
            )
        })
    )
});

//fetch event
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    if (event.request.url.indexOf('firestore.googleapis.com') === -1) {
        event.respondWith(
            caches.match(event.request).then(cacheRes => {
                return cacheRes || fetch(event.request).then(fetchRes => {
                    return caches.open(DYNCACHE).then(cache => {
                        cache.put(event.request.url, fetchRes.clone());
                        return fetchRes;
                    })
                });
            })
        );
    }
});
```

It's not working also on chrome for android and safari on iOS.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This happens because your assets' names don't change when you update them, eg. app.js is always app.js no matter what the contents of the file. From the perspective of the browser, the file didn't change.

You have two main options to handle this:

1. Make sure your server uses correct HTTP headers for all the static assets, eg. ETags or cache: stale-while-revalidate etc. This way you can force the browser to check the server for a new version even if the name of an asset haven't changed.
2. Always change the name of your files when they change in *any* way.

The second option is what most people use when they develop web applications. Usually the tooling, JS bundlers etc. make sure that the filenames change. The filenames are usually in two parts and include the hash of the file contents: for instance `app.8927349789adf8.js` and `styles.329789dfs89sigjg.css`. You don't want to do this by hand , of course, but use something like Webpack or Parcel etc.

You can also use some workarounds like making the browser to request eg. `app.js?XXXXXX` where XXXXX is the current time or something like that. Also, if you want to incorporate some Service Worker library like Workbox, it comes with support for tracking the file content changes even if the names stay the same. Basically Workbox calculates the hash of the files and then caches them using the query param trick, eg. `styles.css?_HASH_OF_THE_FILE`. You can also incorporate this same trick to your hand-written SW file - when your cache names change, just request the files from the server and append something like `?current_time` into all requests. That will force the browser to do the network request.